# How to change the name that evokes a program in Debian-based distros

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, nmap

I want to install a fork of nmap in Kali Linux, but I'm worried that it will conflict with the original program when I type `nmap` in the terminal. Can I change its name from `nmap` to `nmap2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the application to whatever you like. For example, if the application is installed into `/usr/local/bin` then,

```
mv /usr/local/bin/nmap /usr/local/bin/nmap2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `alias` command. `alias` can be used on the command-line like `alias nmap2=/forked/version/of/nmap`. However, that will only last until your shell session exits. Thee more normal use-case is to put it into your shell’s rc file. Which would be `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.zshrc` if you’re using one of the most common shells. The format in the rc file is just like it is on the command-line.

`alias` ia a shell builtin so if you want to read more information about it you can use `help alias` in bash or look for it in `man zshbuiltins`.

Comment: For anyone having the same problem, i'm gonna use this also. Thank you.